# Unit Testing to see if JSON file is null

Tags: json, reactjs, enzyme

I am currently trying to unit test a container that pulls in a static JSON file of phone numbers and passes it to the component to display, however I am not sure how I should go about testing it. The code for the container is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import data from *JSON file location*
import CountryInfo from *component for the country information* ;

class CountryInfoContainer extends React.Component {
 constructor(props, context) {
   super(props, context);
   this.state = {
     numbersJson: null
   };
 }

 async componentWillMount() {
   const numbersJson = data;
   this.setState({ numbersJson });
 }

 render() {
   return (
       <CountryInfo json={this.state.numbersJson} showText={this.props.showText} />
   );
 }
}

export default CountryInfoContainer;
```

I currently have my unit test to look like this

```
import React from 'react';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { mount, configure } from 'enzyme';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import CountryInfoContainer from './CountryInfoContainer';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Successful flows', () => {
  test('checks if json has null entries', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter><CountryInfoContainer /></MemoryRouter >);
    const data = wrapper.find(numbersJson);
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(data.debug);
  });
});
```

Obviously, it doesn't work now because I am not sure how to use the variable numbersJson in the container in the test file or how to check if it is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `numbersJson` is not defined in the scope of your test. If I understand correctly, you are testing that when you first mount the component, that it's state contains a `null` value for the `numbersJson` key.

First of all, you need to mount your component directly without `MemoryRouter`:

```
const wrapper = mount(<CountryInfoContainer />);
```

Then you can write an `expect()` for the state:

```
expect(wrapper.state().numbersJson).toBeNull();
```